# Remove file from git version control without deleting it from the filesystem

Tags: git

How can I remove a file from the git tree without deleting it?

It is easy to `git add` an untracked file to include it by the next commit, however I do not find out how to to remove the file to have it "untracked" again by another commit.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Easy. Just use `git rm --cached` on the file you want to remove from the version control cache but do not want to remove/delete from your filesystem. So if you wanted to remove `foo.txt` from version control like this just run this command:

```
git rm --cached foo.txt
```

As explained in [the official Git `git-rm` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm):

> **--cached**
>
> Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index.
>   Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.

Comment: Ow... I heard of  `--cached` before, but thought it would remove files from the index. Thanks!